# Running Istanbul test coverage for Node modules via shell script wrappers

Tags: shell, istanbul, test-coverage

The scripts in my package.json currently looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./spec/run-local-tests.sh",
  "coverage": "istanbul cover jasmine-node spec",
  "start": "gulp"
}
```

The test script runs this .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Renaming database file produced by previous test run"
mv -f 'shared-local-instance.db' 'shared-local-instance.db.previous'
echo "Starting DynamoDB"
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb &
export JAVA_PID=$!
echo "Running Tests"
./node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node spec
echo "Cleaning up DynamoDB - killing local instance"
kill -9 $JAVA_PID
```

However I now want to change my `coverage` script to run the shell file:

```
"coverage": "istanbul cover ./spec/run-local-tests.sh"
```

But I then get an error that says:

```
echo "Renaming database file produced by previous test run"
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Is there a way that I can get instanbul and my shell file to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM.

The Istanbul docs say:

> The `cover` command can be used to get a coverage object and reports for any arbitrary **node script**.

(emphasis mine)

`istanbul cover` needs a node script. It can't do coverage on shell scripts or any other arbitrary executable.

You could write a shell script that does whatever setup/cleanup you need, then launches `istanbul cover`, and configure it thus:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./spec/run-local-tests.sh",
  "coverage": "./spec/run-local-tests-with-coverage.sh",
  "start": "gulp"
}
```

---

Or you could modify your existing script, perhaps like this:

```
echo "Running Tests"
${COVERAGE} ./node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node spec
```

Then call it with the environment variable set:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./spec/run-local-tests.sh",
  "coverage": "env COVERAGE='istanbul coverage' ./spec/run-local-tests.sh",
  "start": "gulp"
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! p.s. I have read the documentation and knew that istanbul runs node scripts, I just wanted help figuring out how to run my shell script too (I'm new to writing shell scripts). Thanks again for the answer!